# update the height of a DOM element by adding a resize event listener

Tags: vue.js

I would like to make sure that my component has the same height as width. To achieve this I added the **resize** event listener. Currently I have this code

```
<template>
    <div
        :ref="cellId"
    >
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            cellId: '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9)
        };
    },
    methods: {
        updateCellHeight: function() {
            this.$refs[this.cellId].clientHeight = this.$refs[this.cellId].clientWidth;
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateCellHeight);
        this.updateCellHeight();
    },
    destroyed: function() {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateCellHeight);
    }
}
</script>
```

So all I do is generating a unique ID to access the DOM element within the Vue instance. Further I run my event and set the height equal to the width.

When creating multiple components via looping and resizing the window I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'clientHeight'
>   of object '#'
>       at VueComponent.updateCellHeight

How can I access my HTML element and make sure that its height is equal to its width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message is trying to tell you, `clientHeight` is a read only property. You'll probably want to modify the `style.height` property, but keep in mind `clientHeight` includes the padding. Try getting the element style using [Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and getting the width from there.

However, you can actually achieve this without using any JS at all: http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html